# I need to recreate the multiselect after ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I need to recreate the multiselect in "**Local**" after "**Empresa**" ajax response with this data response. I put the information in "**Local**" select but I am not able to recreate the "**Local**" multiselect.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajaxrequests/requestlocals',
    type: 'POST', dataType: 'json',
    data: {empresas:empresas},
    success: function(retorno){
        console.log(retorno);
        $('#ajax_local').html("");
        $.each(retorno, function (valor, chave) {
            $('#ajax_local').append($('<option>', {
                value: valor,
                text : chave
            }));
        });
        $('#ajax_local').multiselect();
    }
});
```

[image: Imagem 1]
[image: Imagem 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to destroy it first;

```
$("#ajax_local").multiselect('destroy');
$("#ajax_local").multiselect();
```

Comment: destroy don't fix the problem. Thanks for your effort.